# How to add data to Redis manually and get cached data in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

My requirement is to keep set of rules in a cache memory and retrieve both Key and Value. As im new to the redis i create a sample rule in the redis client as follows

[image]

can this key and value take through Spring data redis?

if it is possible how? i went through several tutorials i only see set values using redis template and get the relevant value?

Thanks 
Dasun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i went through several tutorials i only see set values using redis
>   template and get the relevant value?

Yes , because that is how most of us do it :)
I really like `RedisTemplate`.
As said in their documentations:

> Helper class that simplifies Redis data access code. Performs
>   automatic serialization/deserialization between the given objects and
>   the underlying binary data in the Redis store.

So my tip is , to do what I did when implementing our entire caching service, to check some of those tutorials, since it would make your life easier.

Comment: My problem is if i set data through redis client can i get them through Redis template?

Comment: Suppose data same as above screenshot. So how can i get using key "name"?

Comment: Sure you can, here is the list of all operations:
https://medium.com/@hulunhao/how-to-use-redis-template-in-java-spring-boot-647a7eb8f8cc

e.g.

`stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get("name")`

Comment: Any Other thing do i have to check?

Comment: Check the tutorial on : https://dzone.com/articles/implementation-of-redis-in-micro-servicespring-boo

You have to set configuration and everything. Follow the steps , don't rush.

Comment: I Have done the exact thing . i can manage to solve it . Suppose if i set a json can that also taken?